# Symfony 2 delete related records

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I try to throw a user friendly error message if I try to delete a record that has linked records in database. I want the solution to be more generic: The goal is to have a listener that would listen to some sort of event. The basic action for deleting a record is :

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Entity entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                'success',
                $this->get('translator')->trans('Entity ' . $entity->getName(). ' was deleted successfully!')
            );
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route'));
    }
```

Now it throws an `Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException`. Of course we can put a `try/catch` block, but I have to put that in every action that I have.

Another solution would be to determine if an entity is linked, but I don't seem to find how to achieve that.

Any suggestions?